# AnkiDroid - How to Left Align Text?

Tags: ankidroid

On AnkiDroid, all text in the flash cards is center aligned. Is there a way to make it left aligned? I'm looking for a solution that does not involve editing each card. For example, is there a setting to make the text left aligned?

Comment: Update on the closed question, a workaround:
You can always put spaces to the ends of the lines to make them equally long. This will manually left align the text. Example:

 List of fruits:
1 Nut______
2 Pineapple
3 Orange___

Comment: @MatthewRead I Agree, great question! Anki including AnkiDroid needs more attention, it is by far the best thing since sliced bread! And thanks to google i found this answer that helped me!

Comment: @MichalCiechan Appreciate your comment, even years later -- SE has since done away with the "Too Localized" on-hold reason, and if users of the app find this info useful then it should definitely be here.  I've cleaned up the older comments.

Comment: [You just have to change the style from text-align: center; in text-align: left;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOQST.jpg)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can align text to the left.

For now there is no WYSIWYG editor, but you can do what you want with some simple HTML:

[image: AnkiDroid left align]

[image: AnkiDroid left align]

If you don't want to do it for each card, modify the card template using Anki Desktop.

Comment: That's why I don't use AnkiDroid

Comment: @Deqing: You will be glad to know that https://code.google.com/p/ankidroid/issues/detail?id=635 has been fixed and there is now a way to align left :-) I updated my answer.

Comment: Tried adding <p align=left> in both AnkiDroid 2.3.2 and Anki desktop, still not working :(

Comment: @Deqing: Please post a new question, including screenshots of your card template and of the content of all fields, thanks!

Comment: New question posted http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/87333/ankidroid-failed-to-left-align-text. Thanks.