# AnkiDroid - failed to Left Align Text

Tags: ankidroid

I'm trying to left align text in card but with no luck.

Tried changing text-align to left in Anki desktop, the card in desktop working fine, but it doesn't affect the card in mobile - it's still center aligned.

Also tried add html tag as follows, but still not working. (AnkiDroid version 2.3.2)

[image: use p align] [image: still centered]
<sup>use p align / still centered (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Comment: Please also post a screenshot of your card template (seen in Anki Desktop). See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F1j1Zx0mXME

Comment: Big thanks! Turning off "Simple interface" fixed the problem.

Comment: @DanHulme: Could you please post your comment as an answer, so that we can upvote/accept it? Thanks! :-)

Comment: @Deqing OK, since that worked, I've written it up as an answer. Please go ahead and accept it so other visitors can see the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use any HTML markup but simple bold/italics in cards, you need to turn off the option **Advanced** -> **Simple interface**.